# In machine learning Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 10) are incompatible

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am getting an error `(Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 10)) are incompatible` in the Keras model below:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1000, input_dim=25088, 
activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
keras.layers.core.Dropout(0.3, noise_shape=None, seed=None)
model.add(Dense(500,input_dim=1000,activation='sigmoid'))
keras.layers.core.Dropout(0.4, noise_shape=None, seed=None)
model.add(Dense(150,input_dim=500,activation='sigmoid'))
keras.layers.core.Dropout(0.2, noise_shape=None, seed=None)
model.add(Dense(units=10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="adam", metrics= 
['accuracy'])
# fitting the model 
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=128,validation_data= 
(X_valid,Y_valid))
```

Comment: Where did `X_train`, `Y_train`, `X_valid`, and `Y_valid` come from.

Answer (score 0):

The output shape of your model is `(None, 10)`, but the shape of `Y_train` is `(None, 2)`. The shapes do not match, this is why you are facing this error. Set the number of units in the final dense layer to 2 and the problem should be fixed. Try this:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1000, input_dim=25088, 
activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
keras.layers.core.Dropout(0.3, noise_shape=None, seed=None)
model.add(Dense(500,input_dim=1000,activation='sigmoid'))
keras.layers.core.Dropout(0.4, noise_shape=None, seed=None)
model.add(Dense(150,input_dim=500,activation='sigmoid'))
keras.layers.core.Dropout(0.2, noise_shape=None, seed=None)
model.add(Dense(units=2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="adam", metrics= 
['accuracy'])
# fitting the model 
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=128,validation_data= 
(X_valid,Y_valid))
```